# How to move up a directory with Terminal in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

When I launch a new Terminal window, it starts me in 'Macintosh HD/Users/MyName'. How can I back out of my user directory, back up to the top level?

Comment: Use "cd /" to get to the root directory.

Comment: or just cd to get to the root directory

Comment: @coolcool1994 — That goes to the user's home directory, not the root directory.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

`cd ..` will back the directory up by one. If you want to reach a folder in the parent directory, you can do something like `cd ../foldername`. You can use the ".." trick as many times as you want to back up through multiple parent directories. For example, `cd ../../Applications` would take you to `Macintosh HD/Applications`

Comment: Big thanks! Macintosh HD/Applications is exactly where I was going.

Comment: cd / will get you to the root directory back

Comment: Make sure to put the space between "cd" and "..", small but may cause a pain if not paying attention.

Comment: @Nofel Make sure you put a space between `cd` and `..`

Answer (score 31):

For Mac Terminal

```
cd ..   # one up
cd ../  # two up
cd      # home directory 
cd /    # root directory
cd "yaya-13" # use quotes if the file name contains punctuation or spaces
```

Comment: `cd` goes to the user's home directory, not the root directory.

Comment: Also `cd ../` is not two up... The command is the same as `cd ..`

Answer (score 18):

Typing `cd` will take you back to your home directory. 
Whereas typing `cd ..` will move you up only one directory (the direct parent of the current directory).

Answer (score 5):

Let's make it even more simple. Type the below after the $ sign to go up one directory:

```
../
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I get the error `-bash: ../: is a directory`. I find it works with `cd ../` though.

Answer (score 5):

To move up a directory, the quickest way would be to add an alias to ~/.bash_profile

```
alias ..='cd ..'
```

and then one would need only to type '..[return]'.

Answer (score 0):

To go to the main/home directory using the below command

"cd ~/." ==> without inverted commas